# Parsing results from LTSpice step function

Tags: ltspice

I have a CLLC circuit in which I am trying to find values of the inductors and capacitors. I know the circuit needs a gain of at least 10 dB at 50kHz and below 1 db at around 30-40KHz. This has to be true while varying the load. I have set up the circuit in ltspice where I am using the .step function to sweep through component values and am looking at the bode plots.

The problem is I have so many graphs on the screen that I cannot keep track of them all. In the 1000s. Is there a way I can only display the simulations which have over 10dB at 50KHz and under 1db below 30Khz? Basically I want to get rid of all the sims that don't meet my criteria. The circuit is way too complex for me to solve mathematical.

It's for a tank in a resonant tank charger. The load will vary from 4ohm to 12homs.  The circuit is bidirectional and it would be helpful if the transfer function is similar in both directions. What other info should I post? I've been trying to make something similar to the circuit in this article. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ho_Sung_Kim3/publication/260496284_Design_Methodology_of_Bidirectional_CLLC_Resonant_Converter_for_High-Frequency_Isolation_of_DC_Distribution_Systems/links/00b7d5347ada7c098b000000/Design-Methodology-of-Bidirectional-CLLC-Resonant-Converter-for-High-Frequency-Isolation-of-DC-Distribution-Systems.pdf
 I understand basic laplace transforms but not enough to put this all together yet. I'm not overly interested in high efficiency, I know the load varies by a lot.

Comment: Maybe reduce the space you step over? You can right click on the plot and select the steps to plot there, but you can only select by paramter, not by plot outcome

Comment: 1st define Rs and R load (min) at gain = 10dB or Q=3 then I'll show you the easy way in 1 minute

Comment: or Collector out and dont care load?

Comment: or SMPS?  switch source?

Comment: It's easy if you give more info.

Comment: hello? what is your ideal response and impedance in/out?  and is that BPF, HPF, or LPF?

Comment: "This has to be true while varying the load" -- this makes it a bit mission impossible, unless you have some sort of feedback.

Comment: I don't know if LTspice is able to select waveforms of specific amplitudes at a certain frequency, but you can use `.meas` to both measure your elements (if they are passed as `.param`), and of the waveforms, for example `.meas x find mag(v(out)) at=5k` will determine the magnitude@5kHz. If you say you have many traces, you can open up the log (Ctrl+L) and then RClick > plot .meas'd data (or something like this). In .AC, by default, the results are in dB, but you can change that with `.opt meascplxfmt=cartesian`.

Comment: What is the source impedance? and why are you doing it the hard way?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing it the hard way?
[image]
[image]

or an easier way.

C1=3.3uF,  L1=4uH, L2=2uH, C2=3.3uF, R=>1.5 Ohm
C1 in series with L1, L2 shunt, C2 series, R load shunt.

If using a voltage source Zs=0

Q > 11dB at 50kHz, < -30dB at 10kHz

Swap L1,L2 for higher Q.